# Reference for homogeneous spaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras

I am a graduate student of differential geometry.
I would like to get an overview over the way, how results are usually obtained for homogeneous spaces by Lie algebraic methods. By definition a Riemannian homogeneous space is a quotient $G/H$ of a Lie group $G$ modulo a closed subgroup $H$ together with an $\mbox{Ad}(H)$-invariant scalar product on a complement to the tangent space of $H$.
As far as I know many results that are difficult to obtain for general manifolds are much easier to get for homogeneous spaces, since one can reduce the problem to a Lie algebraic problem. I would like to get an overview about the way how this method is used. How does one reduce the problem to a Lie algebraic one? Do you know any references in the internet about this method?
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Your sentence "By definition" is unclear. This is not the definition. The definition is a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric on $G/H$. This is equivalent to the datum of a $Ad(H)$-invariant scalar product on $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$. When $H$ is connected the latter is the same as an $ad(\mathfrak{h})$-invariant scalar product on on $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$.

Comment: I recommend the chapter "Homogeneous Spaces" in the book "Comparisons theorems in Riemannian geometry" by Cheeger&Ebin. Two classical books are Helgason's "Differential Geometry etc" and Vol II of Kobayashi&Nomizu "Foundations of Differential Geometry".

Answer (score 3):

*An Introduction to Lie Groups and the Geometry of Homogeneous Spaces* written by By *Andreas Arvanitogeōrgos* is a useful reference [Read online here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z4vxBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&dq=homogeneous%20space&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8jsOc8djPAhWFOsAKHXADBcgQ6AEIRDAG#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Another good reference for physic and math students is *Differential Geometry and Lie Groups for Physicists* written by *Marián Fecko* [Read on google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=vQR0mN1dgUEC&pg=PA296&dq=homogeneous%20space&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiay5Op89jPAhWCJcAKHeZoA5Q4ChDoAQhHMAc#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

A. L. Onishchik, **Topology of transitive transformation groups** is an excellent book for the study of compact homogeneous Riemannian manifolds.

Gorbatsevich, V. V.; Onishchik, A. L. **Lie groups of transformations** is an excellent book about more general homogeneous spaces.